# Representing Time in C++

Tags: c++, methods

im creating a constructor to set the default time to midnight. My question is how would you represent time as an int because i have other functions that add minutes,hours,etc to it.

```
Datatype IsMidnight;

DataType SetToMidnight( datatype M){

//set the default time to midnight not sure how to represent midnight as HH:MM
// example datatype= 12:00; 

}
```

Comment: You might want to start by googling for "time_t", then proceed to something like "C++ chrono".

Comment: Midnight is `00:00`.

Comment: Err, standard time functions (like those in <time.h> or <chrono>) always measure time in seconds represented as some unsigned data type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: What about those days in spring and autumn when the clocks switch?  Clocks are complex.

Comment: Well for this one All i wanted was to be able to set the time to midnight 12:00 AM(thats why i wanted to know how time should be represented if you are setting you own time) and then the user could input Hours and Minutes and the time would change depending on their input so 12:00 AM user + (01:40)= 01:40AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for C++11's, [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

> The chrono library defines three main types ([durations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), clocks, and
>   time points) as well as utility functions and common typedefs.

You can also look for Boost which has a [Date/Time library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Comment: Okay cool i was looking at it and i just did not know how to add my own time. But thanks ill check it out :)